# missing mapbox-gl.css with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

my browser console is showing me an error, that the .css is missing. 
Indeed the map is only like "half loaded" .
It worked before, but now I have implemented a directory structure like so:

in my src:

```
App.jsx
directory_1
   directory_2
      map_file.jsx
```

I'm using `import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css"` in my map_file.jsx . Do I need to specify the path to the .css?

Comment: check your webpack configuration, perhaps you're missing something. Check css-loader and style loader, or what loader that you're using?

Comment: I really don't have any clue, where my webpack config could be. as well my style loader or css loader. I'm using react, that's it :-)

Comment: oh so you're using create-react-app, alright.
found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909438/missing-mapbox-css-using-react

can this solution works for you?

Comment: I found this solution, too, didn't work. when I zoom in my web app, the map is switching to the correct mode. I guess it's something with loading of the css. The console is giving me a `href="blob:http://localhost:3000/53a8fe2b-0464-4ab8-aa7d-5f322ffe59e7"` as link type of the css

Comment: It's hard to tackle the problem since the abstraction of create-react-app makes it harder to configure by our own.

Comment: My suggestion is to configure your react app by yourself by using webpack + babel, there are many tutorials around internet to get started, good luck.

Comment: however I found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-gl

have you used that?